# Cannot query on a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically I did query and it didn't work
'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM''

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT Group_ID, count(ID)
FROM dbo.S1_Users
WHERE Service_Plan = 'Multi User Foreign (B)'
GROUP BY Group_ID
HAVING count(ID) = 1
)
```

I know it's simple to fix and I searched the google but failed to find the right one

Can any body to explain about that?

Comment: Are you missing an ending paren?  `SELECT COUNT(*)` <-- Note )

Comment: oh sorry actually that's just a typo, edited

Comment: You could lose the count(ID) from the select inside the inline view I should think.

Comment: You also need a dummy alias name after the last parenthesis.  Most folks just use an ` A` for this.

Comment: Sans the typo, it's a perfectly legitmate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name the dummy table and name the `count(ID)` column from the inner query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT Group_ID, count(ID) as ID_Count
FROM dbo.S1_Users
WHERE Service_Plan = 'Multi User Foreign (B)'
GROUP BY Group_ID
HAVING count(ID) = 1
) as A
```

You could also remove the count entirely sense you are not using it

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT Group_ID
FROM dbo.S1_Users
WHERE Service_Plan = 'Multi User Foreign (B)'
GROUP BY Group_ID
HAVING count(ID) = 1
) as A
```

Comment: thanks, tried but it says: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'A'.

Comment: Sorry I posted at the wrong place, Thank you very much for your right answer, but may I ask why this works?

Comment: For the `count(ID)` error, it is because SQL requires all items to have names, even if you are not using them in your main query when you use a sub-query. For the `From` error, all sub queries must be aliased, it is a requirement of SQL.

Comment: so, whatever in the 2nd layer query, every aggregate one should have a alias, otherwise there would be an error right?

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Group_ID, count(ID) As cnt
    FROM dbo.S1_Users
    WHERE Service_Plan = 'Multi User Foreign (B)'
    GROUP BY Group_ID
    HAVING count(ID) = 1
) A
```

Comment: You code will still not work, there is a 2nd error. `count(ID)` needs a name.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yep, I missed that on the inner COUNT(ID), though I am not getting that error on my SQL Server for some reason... ?  Anyway, I have corrected it.

Comment: the error may be SQL version dependent. (maybe it does not get raised in 2008R2 or 2012?)

Comment: @user2438187 Everything that comes out of the FROM clause is supposed to have a unique name so that it can be referenced and distinguished in the other clauses. Tables and Views are automatically named after themselves if no alias is assigned, but expressions have no default name, so one must be supplied.